# Use field aliases in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

How ... or **can** I use a field alias a.k.a. `field as val` in the very same select-clause and the where-clause ?

```
select
    a.LONG_NAME_I_CANT_REMEMBER as val1,
    a.NAME_I_DONT_WANT_2_REMEMBER as val2,
    val1-val2 as diff
from
    random_table a
where
    (val1 > 12)
```

There a re no inline-view / inline queries and it's **not about table aliases**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias you define in the `SELECT` clause in your `WHERE` clause.  Logically, determining which rows to return (applying the `WHERE` clause) comes before determining which columns to display (the `SELECT` list) so when the `WHERE` clause is processed, the aliases don't exist yet.

You could, of course, refactor the query so that you're selecting and aliasing the data in an inline view and then apply the `WHERE` clause outside that view.  Something like

```
select a.*,
       val1-val2 as diff
  from (select a.LONG_NAME_I_CANT_REMEMBER as val1,
               a.NAME_I_DONT_WANT_2_REMEMBER as val2,
          from random_table a) a
 where (val1 > 12)
```